# jquery tablesorter access internal config parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

i'm working since hours on this issue without any success, hope to get some help here!
I use the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) plugin to sort table on client side.
First of all, I set an default sort order and initalize the sorter-plugin:

```
var defaultSort=[[4,1]];
$("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList:defaultSort});
```

Which does not work (does not sort) while this works:

```
 $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[4,1]]});
```

Can't see a reason for this behavior.

Later, I add columns dynamically by using getJSON. After adding a line, I have to update the tablesorter and order again (because of the new rows). For that: read the current "sortList" and try to apply this list:

```
$("#myTable").trigger("update");
sortOrder=$("#myTable")[0].config.sortList;
setTimeout('$("#myTable").trigger("sorton",['+sortOrder+']);',1);
```

But this does not work. There is no ordering.
An console.info(sortOrder) returns 4 instead of [[4,1]].
Why?

But all this code works, if the sortList is hardcoded, like:

```
$("#myTable").trigger("update");
setTimeout('$("#myTable").trigger("sorton",[[[4,1]]]);',1);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var myTable = $("#myTable");
var sortOrder=myTable.trigger("update")[0].config.sortList;
setTimeout(function(){
    myTable.trigger("sorton",[sortOrder]);
},1);
```

in your 3rd example you wrote

```
setTimeout('$("#myTable").trigger("sorton",['+sortOrder+']);',1);
```

sortOrder is having toString() called on it when you stick it in that string. That's at least one of the reasons it's not working.

Comment: thank you, for your answer.. your "try this" block works. How to avoid :"sortOrder is having toString() called on it when you stick it in that string."??

Comment: setTimeout('$("#myTable").trigger("sorton",[sortOrder]);',1); but wrapping it in a function is cleaner